# Dynamically adding elements to controlgroup jQuery mobile 1.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I always faced problems while adding or removing elements from `controlgroup` dynamically. Thankfully, `JQM 1.3` has provided an example for that.

Link: http://www.uglymongrel.com/jqm/touch/demos/examples/controlgroups/dynamic-controlgroup.php

But the example code is very confusing. Can anyone explain how the `container()` method is working and what is the `buttonMarkup()` method?

```
$( "#my-controlgroup" ).controlgroup( "container" )[ $( this ).attr( "id" ) ]( $el );
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably know that **HTML** you write for a **jQuery Mobile** is in fact not the same with a final result. When **jQuery Mobile** builds the page it changes its final **HTML** content.

This is important to know if you what to understand what is **[container element](http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/#method-container)**. When this method is executed:

```
$( "#my-controlgroup" ).controlgroup( "container" )[ $( this ).attr( "id" ) ]( $el );
```

method will populate **`controlgroup`**  **`#my-controlgroup`** content. Just accessing **`$('#my-controlgroup')`** will not give us correct **`DOM`** position of a **`controlgroup`** content.

This part:

```
[ $( this ).attr( "id" ) ]
```

is here only to represent n-th **`controlgroup`**  in an array of **`controlgroups`**.

More information about this can be found in an official documentation **[HERE](http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/#method-container)**.

Regarding the second question, this method:

```
buttonMarkup()
```

is used to change **`jQuery Mobile`** button look. For example this will change button corners look:

```
$( "a" ).buttonMarkup({ corners: false });
```

or change the button icon:

```
$( "a" ).buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

This can be found **[HERE](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/)**.

Comment: Still couldn't understand why we need container? This line is causing confusion : "is here only to represent n-th controlgroup in an array of controlgroups". There is only one control group here.

Comment: If you look carefully you will see 3 controlgroups in an example from your link. Container is DIV that contains controllgroup content.

Comment: There are three controlgroups but the content is being added in "my-controlgroup" only, then why do we need array for that. Also the code is bit confusing. How the element is getting appended without using append? I tried a similar code and it isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/KH6KA/

Comment: Thats not array. I debugged the code. Its adding "append" or "prepend". $("#my-controlgroup").controlgroup( "container" )["append"]($el);

Comment: @dejavu is correct.  `[ $( this ).attr( "id" ) ]` evaluates to "append" or "prepend", which are methods of the container object.  It's a shame the answer with the most upvotes is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $( "#my-controlgroup" ).controlgroup( "container" )[ $( this ).attr(
 "id" ) ]( $el );
```

this translates to

```
$( "#my-controlgroup" ).controlgroup( "container" ).append( $el );
OR
$( "#my-controlgroup" ).controlgroup( "container" ).prepend( $el );
```

where $el is notning but new element that you want to append or prepend to the group. Confusing part in this demo code is that they have kept method names(append, prepend) in ID attribute of clicked element, that's how they are dynamically able to identify the operation based on element clicked.